# Is there any way to fetch child node's child data in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch products data according to child "dry" and then value "tone" i am not able to find any solution.If anyone knows please guide me. [image]

Answer (score 2):

if what you mean is to fetch products based on the tone then you can do

```
FirebaseDatabase
       .getInstance()
       .getReference("products")
       .child("Dry")
       .orderByChild("tone")
       .equalTo("V.Fair OR whatever tone type") // Add tone you want here
       .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
        new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //Do whatever with the data
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        }
);
```

if what you mean is order the products based on the tone then you can just remove the .equalTo

*****Do not forget to index your data on tone** ***

Docs on indexing data:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

Comment: it won't work in android

Comment: updated to reflect android instead of javascript sdk :)

Comment: good, you are getting a up now